# How to refresh a layout after ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I try to do a menu with a hide button. When I press the hide button, i do `objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myLayout, "translationY"...` to move the layout up.

My problem is when I move all the layout up, it didn't grow, it only move up with his fixed size. I don't know how to refresh the size of the layout to `match_parent` so my 2nd layout will take all the place.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more, are you inflating new layout after animation ends?

Comment: Maybe fillAfter=true option works can work. If not on your animationListener's onAnimationEnd method you can set the position of your menu like (0, -200)

Answer (score 0):

Kick off example:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myLayout, "translationY"...);
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener() { 

    @Override  
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams).width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;  
    } 
});
```

Comment: While the idea is there, this code doesn't even compile and uses weird notation (`setWidth` for a property?). There isn't any `AnimatorListeners` where you only need to override the `onAnimationEnd` as well.
I'd suggest you re-write your answer a bit...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achive this effect using only translation. **Translating object still keep its bounds** in layout (you can see it when you turn on *Developer options -> Show layout bounds* on your device). It's just drawing in a different place.

I don't know what you exactly want to do, so if that tip is not enough, try to give more details. For now I can only propose animating one of your views' height.